# process freezes during make on linphone for android

Tags: compilation, android-ndk, freeze, mingw32, linphone

I've been trying to build linphone for android for a few days now but I've come to a point where I'm unable to fix the problem I encounter in the build process.

I've been following the provided readme step by step and also tried several ways explained here in SO questions but non get me passed this current point.

http://pastebin.com/gxmc2gwZ

The above pasbin link shows the output of my mingw32 window when I run make. At the end it just holds. It feels like make just goes into an infinite loop. I've left it running overnight but it stays at that exact spot. The only way to stop it is ctrl-c.

Sofar I've used 3 difirent android NDK builds thinking there might be an incompatability.
r8e, r7c and r7 dont work. r7 doesn't even get this far.

I've also tried running make with SHELL="sh -x" but the resulting output is hardly difirent (as expected).

I've tried searching on google but all hits always show an error in the logs. Mine does not.

If anyone has any idea what can cause it to hang that would be REALLY appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by running ndk-build.cmd from the project root directory in a command prompt instead of using make in mingw wich called the linux version. my project is now happely compiling along.